# How to make slider work on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, idangero

I used idangero swiper for swiping the images,here my problem is when page loads the swiper is not working, when I reloading it, working properly (i.e. it is not taking transform property when page loads).

Js code:

```
  vm.onSwipe= function () {
            vm.tslider = new Swiper('.tslider ', {
                slidesPerView: 3 
            });
    };
```

Html:

```
     <div class="swiper-wrapper tslider ">
                <div class="swiper-slide"  prsnlty-Image-Slider="onLoadSlider">
                    <div  ng-repeat="data in smyData"> 
                        <img ng-src="{{data.img}} />
                        <p class="trtstxt">{{data.txt}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You're not going to get much help without posting your code. See here for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you seeing any error in you console ?

Comment: @Ancient   no error,it works properly when i reload the page(css transform property is not applying)on page load.